# Pagination Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

A problem I've been running into recently is dealing with pagination of Json I receive from the server. I can work around some instances but would like a better approach. So the structure I receive here illustrates a problem I can run into:

```
Modules
{
    ID
    Title
    Description
    Lessons
    {
        edges
        {
            node
            {
                ID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for the lessons array, the server inserts the edges and node elements because of the use of pagination. So what I would expect instead is:

```
Modules
{
    ID
    Title
    Description
    Lessons
    {
        ID
    }
}
```

The main problem however with this is that it stops me being able to deserialize the object easily, i.e. I can't do this:

```
Modules[] modules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Modules[]>(json, settings);
```

My Lesson and Module class for reference is just:

```
public class Lesson
{
    public int ID;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Module
{
    public string ID;
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public Lesson[] Lessons;
}
```

So just wondered if anyone else had come across a similar issue and what solutions they've done to work around it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the real JSON object?

Comment: The sample json is a snippet of the real JSON I receive. Have added what I expect as a comparison.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with pagination in JSON... Seems to be your service is producing JSON you're not expecting. That's something you need to work out with the producer of your service. Either have the service adjust what it produces or adjust your expectations.

Comment: "The sample json is a snippet of the real JSON I receive." Then it is invalid JSON...

Comment: @HereticMonkey thus why I'm asking the question? Asking whether there's a simple adjustment I can make to account for it?

Like it's valid JSON as other software is using it

Answer (score 0):

Your serialization should work just fine if you create concrete objects for 'edges' and 'node'.

I assume 'lessons' it an array of 'edge' object. 'edge' object contains the 'node' object, which has the property 'id'

Comment: How do you mean? Like if I'm understanding correctly, that might work but would surely involve declaring every object to have edges and nodes?

Comment: You can alternatively declare 'Lessons' as an array of JObjects, which will deserialize just fine but you will need to use some alternative methods to access the content of this JObject

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out a bit of a workaround (sort of following Zero Cool's answer) which is to make generic Edges and Node classes. i.e.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Edges<T>
{
    public Node<T>[] edges;
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public T node;
}
```

And then declare them where I am using Pagination. It's not lovely but works alright as I usually know what is/isn't paginated.

Would still be interested if there's a cleaner way.